# Sencha Touch / ExtJS: how to store a variable for later use?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

Is it possible for one method in a class to store a value that another method can use later on?

For example, here's a snippet from one of my Ext.Panel instances:

```
app.views.EstablishmentDetail = Ext.extend(Ext.Panel, {
dockedItems: [{
    xtype: 'toolbar',
    title: 'View establishment',
    items: [
        {
            text: 'Back',
            ui: 'back',
            listeners: {
                'tap': function () {
                    Ext.dispatch({
                        controller: app.controllers.establishments,
                        action: 'index',
                        animation: {type:'slide', direction:'right'}
                    });
                }
            }
        },
        {xtype:'spacer'},
        {
            id: 'Map',
            text: 'Map',
            ui: 'action',
            listeners: {
                'tap': function () {
                    Ext.dispatch({
                        controller: app.controllers.establishments,
                        action: 'showMap',
                        id: this.record.getId(),
                        data: this.record.data,
                        record: this.record
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}],
styleHtmlContent:true,
scroll: 'vertical',
```

I'd like to have a variable in this class-- call it 'myVariable' that I can pass to a property in the dispatcher you see above, 'showMap'.  (I'd like to initialize its value from another method call.)

But in all the examples I've seen on ExtJS, when you subclass something like Ext.Panel, it seems you can only refer to pre-existing properties (like 'title') or create new functions.  Is there a mechanism for saving a variable during one method call, then using that variable in a different method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can add any properties you want to a subclass.  The only tricky thing about sharing data between methods like you're doing is that the this pointer refers to the item, not the subclass.

I think the easy thing to do is override the initComponent method so that you can use closures to share variables between your handlers, e.g.:

```
app.views.EstablishmentDetail = Ext.extend(Ext.Panel, {
initComponent: function () {
    var me = this;  //me will always refer to the view instance
    me.myVariable = yourMethod();
    me.dockedItems = [
        ...same code as you had before {
        listeners: {
            'tap': function () {
                Ext.dispatch({
                    someProp: me.myVariable
                });
            }
        }
    }];

    //You have to remember to do this anytime you override the initComponent method!!!
    app.views.EstablishmentDetail.superclass.initComponent.apply(this, arguments);
}});
```

IMHO, anytime you're using the this pointer in your subclass, it'll be less confusing if you move your code into initComponent and use closures.  You don't have to but then you'd have to move up/down the parent/child component chain.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks Jason.  I've been experimenting with your suggestions, and have added 'me' to the properties list like so:  'me: {}'.

I then do as you listed above, initializing it in initComponent with 'me = this'.  The reason I did it this way is that if I put 'var me' in initComponent, for whatever reason 'me' did not exist in the later Ext.dispatch call.  (Please note that I kept my dockedItems array as-is, and didn't convert it to 'me.dockedItems')

I'm not sure why this is the case, but the way I've done it appears to work.  Thanks much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

A nice way of putting varibles on the class is using the Ext.apply method.

```
Ext.apply(this, {
myVar1 : myVar1,
myProp1: myProp1,
})
```

The reason why the varible didn't exist in the Dispatch call is that it is not in the correct scope.  The default scope of the listener function will be in this case the toolbar.  You have to set the scope to this on the listener.

To answer your question you can do something like this :

```
initComponent: function(){
    Ext.apply(this, {
    dispatchAction : 'showMap'
    });
    app.views.EstablishmentDetail.superclass.initComponent.call(this);
}
```

...

```
listeners: {
                tap:{
                    fn : function () {
                    Ext.dispatch({
                        controller: app.controllers.establishments,
                        action: this.dispatchAction,
                        id: this.record.getId(),
                        data: this.record.data,
                        record: this.record
                    });
                }
                scope: this
            }
        }
```

There are many valid ways of using the listeners object and this is one of them.  I prefer using the on/addListener method.